# javascript call a function on event

Tags: javascript, webrtc, peerjs

Please explain me the difference between these two statements. which one is calling the function 'connect'. connect is a user defined function.

```
`peer.on('connection', connect);`
```

and

```
f.on('open', function() {
    connect(f);
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both will call `connect` when the event occurs.  The main difference is that the first one gets its arguments set by the event subsystem since it is called directly by whatever manages the events.  If your function either doesn't use any arguments or its arguments match up exactly with what the event system passes, then the first one works fine.

In the second one, you control the arguments sent to `connect(f)` so you can make the arguments anything you want.  So, if you want to control the arguments yourself, then the second block of code gives you that option.

Answer (score 1):

There really isn't much of a difference aside from example one using a named function as the callback and the second example using an anonymous function as the callback. Named callbacks are useful if you need to reuse them or if you just want to have more control over the organization of your callbacks.

Either way, the functions will be called after the execution of 'on' is complete.

For more information about callbacks have a look at http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/

Comment: You missed that the main difference is that in the second block of code, you control the arguments passed to `connect()` rather than just accepting whatever the event handling system passes.  That is, in my opinion, the main reason for using the second form.

Comment: I interpreted the question as named callback vs anonymous callback, however in the context you interpreted it (probably more accurate), you provided a much better answer. +1 from me.

Comment: Classy move that you upvoted a competing answer. I like the reference you offered to help understand callbacks.